# How to get angular js files concatination and minification in same way as done my use min plugin for grunt

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I have tried concatinating and uglifying the files(app.js, controllers, services and filters) as it is process by use min plugin but the output i am getting is not correct.
Can anyone tell me about similar plugin or way which can help me produce same output, I want to specify those files in grunt file not in the index.html (as done while using use min plugin)

Regards and thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the grunt file you are currently using. What do you mean "it is not correct"? Does it minify at all?

Comment: Please post your gruntfile.js and index.html.

Answer (score 0):

in angular you must do this ...

```
myApp.controller("MyController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
}]);
```

THIS WILL NOT WORK WHEN MINIFYING ...

```
myApp.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
});
```

this applies to services, etc, also